# How do I update/add multiple DBs in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The bulletin board is scraped and stored in MongoDB with Python pymongo.

We would like to add data if it is missing or update it if it exists and the values are different.

How can I do this?

Previous Code

```
b = dict(title=thread_title, url=thread_url, res=sorted(all_res))
collection.insert(b)
```

Trying Code

```
collection.update_one({"$set":{"title": thread_title}}, {"$set":{"url": thread_url}}, {"$set":{"res": sorted(all_res)}}, upsert=True)
```

Error Code

> TypeError Collection.update_one() got multiple values for argument
> 'upsert'

There are about 200 MongoDB documents available.

> _id 62459b8d6ebc7c7b3e14b3ad
>
> field:title "THREAD TITLE"
>
> field:url "URLURLURL"
>
> field:res Array 0 "#100 2022/02/20 13:22 comment blah blah blah" 1
> "#101 2022/02/20 13:23 comment blah blah blah"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mongo update official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

In your update query the filter part is missing:

```
collection.update_one(
     {
     // Your selection criteria for the update. The same query selectors as in the find() method
       "_id" : ObjectId("62459b8d6ebc7c7b3e14b3ad") //for example
     },
     {
       "$set":{
          "title": thread_title,
          "url": thread_url, 
          "res": sorted(all_res)
       }, 
        upsert=True
   })
```

The above query will update the document with id = 62459b8d6ebc7c7b3e14b3ad in your collection

Comment: What should I do if I have almost 200 cases?

Comment: if you wish to do the update on all the records in your use the below query collection,collection.update_one(
     {},
     {
       "$set":{
          "title": thread_title,
          "url": thread_url, 
          "res": sorted(all_res)
       }, 
        upsert=True
   })

Comment: Thanks, I was able to update the DB. What I wanted to do was to include elements that did not exist in the DB, so I used pandas to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to 'separate' your line code, you will see that you're giving the function 4 arguments, each set you gave is an argument so `upsert` is taking as value `{"$set":{"res": sorted(all_res)}}`, you shouldn't separate the 'update' argument

In addition to that, the update_one function take a filter (it's not an optional argument, you should always give a filter).

There is the definition of the update_one function

```py
update_one(filter, update, upsert=False, bypass_document_validation=False, collation=None, array_filters=None, hint=None, session=None)
```

And finally, if you want to update multiple instances at the same time you should consider update_many function (it basically works the same way as update_one).

This code should work, and remember to add a filter.

```py
collection.update_one(
    {
        # your filter here for exemple
        "id" : id
    },
    {
        "$set":{
            "title": thread_title,
            "url": thread_url,
            "res": sorted(all_res)
        }
    }, 
    upsert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing update_one to update_many and got a `cannot encode object: <built-in function id>, of type: <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>` error.

Maybe I don't understand filters and what should I specify in this case?

Comment: The filter in an update function is actually the same type of query you would use in a find function. For example, you can specify {} for all the documents to pass the filter, or you can use 'gt' for greater than, 'lt' for lower than, etc. [here is the list of query operators you can use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/) as well as examples on how to use them

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn MongoDB. I'll check tomorrow to see if the site is up to April Fool's specs and I can't get it.